# Wrong values after reading back data with fread in C

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I am using `tmpfile()` to create a file (so it's automatically opened in **binary mode**).
Then I write some `floats` in it with `fwrite()`. All these `floats` are > 0.

**The problem is that when I try to read these values (that are >0) back with `fread()`, I get negative values!**

The values I write are `out[i][j][couche]` which are OK (it is impossible for them to be <0 because of their definition). The problem is at the end (`fread`).

```
void flou_bis (FILE * fp, PIXRVB **out, PIXRVB **in, int np, int nl, int rayon, int couche){
    int i,j,k,l,nb;
    float ret1, ret2;
    float rCouche;

    /* Other things not relevant..
    (process the values of array out[][][] ...)*/

    for (i=0; i<nl; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<np; j++)
        {
            fwrite ( &(out[i][j][couche]) , sizeof(float), 1, fp);
        }
    }

    rewind(fp);
    /*fsync(fp); // Useless
    rewind(fp);*/

    printf("%d float read\n", fread ( &ret2, sizeof(float), 1, fp)); /*Here is the problem!!! */
    printf("%f\n", ret2);
}
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing into `fopen()`?

Comment: are you positive you're writing positive values?  is it possible your handling of the "out" pointer is wrong and you end up fwrite-ing from different memory than you want?

Comment: maybe add "if (i==0 && j==0) printf("first float %f\n", out[0][0][couche]);" to see what you actually write...

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't call fopen since tmpfile() opens the file automatically

Comment: @Roland: I don't know if the values written are correct but a printf of the array out[][][] just before writting its values is OK

Comment: @Roland "if (i==0 && j==0) printf("first float %f\n", out[0][0][couche]);" returns 196.000. It's normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I needed to create a temp variable to force the cast:

```
float ent = (float) out[i][j][couche];
fwrite ( &ent, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
```

without the (float) it doesn't work, I have no idea why
Thank you all for helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Print out the value you're accessing in `out`, to verify that the indexing is working, both as float and as bytes.
2. Check that `fwrite()` doesn't fail.
3. Print the contents of the file.